# psychopy waitKeys return differs between computers

Tags: key, psychopy

When I run the PsychoPy-coder-demo-program "what_key.py" and press shift-1 I got in the console the following keys:

['lshift']
['exclamation']

But on another computer it's

['lshift']
['1']

Any idea why this differs?

Comment: Just to test the obvious: did you hold SHIFT while pressing 1 on the second computer? Are both running same or different operating systems and versions of psychopy?

Comment: We are using the same version of PsychoPy but running on different OS: Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7.

Comment: And yes - the participants task is to enter a ! So we tested it using the Pschopy coder demo program. I also tried using an other keyboard (wirelss) but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens but the default key-handling code comes from pyglet so, presumably, it's just that pyglet (or the operating system itself) provides differently. i.e. I'm passing the buck; this isn't a bug in PsychoPy's code ;-)

Either way, I'm afraid the workaround is to handle the both key options in your code. Alternatively, switch to using iohub for keyboard events which returns both the character ("!") and the key name ("1")